# Getting an average rank when not every ranking covers the whole set

Tags: missing-data, ranking, mean

I am performing a survey study. In one question, responders were asked to select 5 factors that they consider most important out of a list of 17. They were then asked to rank those 5 selections in order of most to least important. So, each responder gave me their top 5 ranked. I'm now realizing that I want to have a ranking of all 17 qualities, but I don't know if I can do that statistically because each responder only gave a ranking for the top 5, rather than ranking all 17. In other words, I don't know how to get average ranking for "factor xyz" because if it wasn't selected in the top 5, it didn't get a ranking. My research online was pointing me towards Spearman's footrule or Kendall distance. I would greatly appreciate some help with this.

Comment: please help! you'd be a quarantine hero!

Comment: You would know that the one not ranked are somewhere in place 1-12, so you could try incomplete rankings. Maybe a Bayesian model?  Maybe  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.01158.pdf

Comment: thank you. I tried reading the paper but I don't have a statistics background and I am lost.  I will seriously venmo you for a quarantine carry-out meal if you could meet with me on zoom to walk me through this.  I have the data sets, i just don't know how to proceed.